# _THROW not defined in GCC?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

Please tell me where the _THROW macro is defined in GCC4 or how to define it manually

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void test() { _THROW(std::range_error,"Test"); }
```

Comment: `_THROW` isn't part of standard C++. Why would you not write `throw std::range_error("Test");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to throw an exception in C++, use the standard C++ `throw` keyword:

```
 throw std::range_error("Test");
```

Please refrain from using some compiler-specific **internal** macro.

---

If you **must** define it, here you go:

```
#define _THROW(e, ...) throw e(__VA_ARGS__)
```